# Call Multiple ajax request in series or parallel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 functions.

```
load_graphs('national','','container-natl-rates','container-natl-counts')
load_graphs('division','Western','container-west-rates','container-west-counts')
load_graphs('division','Eatern','container-east-rates','container-east-counts')
```

load_graphs is a function that performs a ajax call and creates a graph.

Currently, this calls are done asynchronously but I want to perform like a call back after completing each individual calls.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to write callbacks or what ??

Comment: Can you modify load_graphs?

Comment: I have close to 6 functions to be called one after another, so my current approach looks messy

Comment: try using a `wrapper`/`generic` function to call the `load_graphs` function sequentially. Also you may have to edit your `load_graphs` function to return a `bool` or something that you can check on the completion of each call & then proceed with the next call.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use callbacks like so:

```
function load_graphs(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, done) {
    // then do stuff and when that stuff is done
    // call your callback (in this case I named it "done")
    done();
}
```

Then in your method invocation

```
load_graphs('national','','container-natl-rates','container-natl-counts', function() {
    // first load_graphs() is complete
    load_graphs('division','Western','container-west-rates','container-west-counts', function() {
        // second load_graphs() is complete
        load_graphs('division','Eatern','container-east-rates','container-east-counts', function() {
            // third load_graphs() is complete
        })
    })
})
```

There are other more advanced options, like using third party tools like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [co](https://github.com/tj/co)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change `load_graphs` and insert a callback call, you will have to use some other listener that indicates when `load_graphs` is done.

For example, you say that the function paints a graph, so there is probably some affect that you can track. Perhaps a `<div>` changes its width, perhaps a global variable is set to current timestamp value. Something should happen that you can catch, and it really depends on the rest of your code, which you have not provided.

After the first `load_graphs` call, set up a `setInterval` to continuously check for such indicator, and then run the next `load_graphs` call in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using promises.

Using a promise is a great way to handle things like this where the next task requires a value from the previous task (or at least for the previous task to be completed first).

https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies